# DNS server in windows

Tags: windows, dns, network-programming, winpcap

I'm trying to write a DNS server for windows, using WinPcap. The coding seems to be working and it's answering to the queries. But before each response, windows is sending an ICMP packet, saying "Destination unreachable (port unreachable)". It's like my windows doesn't know that i'm going to answer on port 53, so it assumes that it's going to be unreachable or something. I really don't know. I've also disabled my firewall. Server and Client are both on my windows, using GNS3. I'm also using my Microsoft Loopback interface.
 [image]

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using WinPcap for this? DNS is implemented over UDP (and/or TCP) by listening on port 53. You obviously *can* respond to DNS requests by sniffing raw packets and fabricating responses but that's certainly the hard way. Why not just create a datagram socket, bind it to port 53 and use standard socket send/receive calls? Then you only need to do the DNS part and let the OS take care of the IP/UDP part. (BTW it's correct and quite understandable that the "port unreachable" ICMP is being sent if there's nothing bound to port 53.)

Comment: @GilHamilton
Thanks. Yes i know socket would be a better choice, but to be honest, i've always found socket really hard and not understandable. With pcap, i always know what's going on and i can do almost whatever i want. it's just easier for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course Windows doesn't know that because your app isn't actually listening to (i.e. accepting) the port 53. When the Windows receives a UDP packet from the loopback, then it checks its destination port and if nobody is opening the port it sends ICMP error.

To avoid the error, you have two choices; open the port 53 or don't let the Windows receive packets you send.

For the former, create another app that binds port 53 to a socket and just discard packets it receives via the socket, and run it with your packet capture app.

For the latter, set the destination address (IP or MAC) to one that is not assigned to no one.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using portpeeker to listen on the port and the problem was solved. :)